# $lookup won't use indexes in second $match. How can we scale?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

In MongoDB 3.6 we have a collection `Products` which at the moment has 150k documents, and we need to store for each product its price per shop. At the moment there are about 1000 shops.

Our strategy is to create a second collection, let's call it `ProductShops`:

```
{
    _id: "product_shop_id_1",
    productId: "product_id_1",
    shopId: "shop_id_1",
    price: 15,
    stock: 3,
    enabled: true
}
```

Since we need to query using filters in both collections, e.g. fetch the products that are in stock in X shop, and belong in Y category (product category is stored in `Products` collection), we will be making an aggretation query to Products collection, filter the results, then lookup to the `ProductShops` collection, then filter the results again.

The aggregation pipeline looks like this:

```
[
    match,
    sort,
    lookup,
    unwind,
    match,
    project,
    skip,
    limit
]
```

The problem however is that, as stated in the documentation of mongodb, the second match will not use indexes, which renders lookup useless when working with millions of documents and a request happens to scan the whole collection (eg when the results are less than the limit). We had it tested and in our current data size it might take up to 30 seconds.

We tried using the new syntax of `$lookup` which allows for an embedded pipeline and do the filtering there, which seems to run faster, but it will not filter out a product that matched zero `ProductShops` documents. So we still need to filter them out in a later step either using `$match` or using `$unwind` with `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : false`, which makes the query slow again.

Is there a way to bypass this limitation?

Comment: Post please sample data, we try to help debug it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to bypass this limitation, if you post your aggregation i can try and help make it more efficient.

"Relational" dependencies are not the strong suit for unstructured Databases like Mongo, Usually the "best practice" to increase query performance is to duplicate the data, meaning adding the `category` field to `ProductsShops`. It feels "wrong" if your used to structured DB's but here with Mongo not only will this not be frowned upon but is recommended.

Something to consider when doing this is that you sacrifice "integrity", meaning when you update a products category syncing it to the other collection won't be atomic obviously, With that said i'm assuming that action does not happen often as products don't get new categories everyday.